# Constructors and inheritance?

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a class named Car and another which inherits from Car called SuperCar. How can I ensure that Car's costructor is called in SuperCar's constructor? Do I simply do: Car.Car(//args);?

Thanks

Comment: It will be called by default or do you want to invoke a specific constructor of Car to create SuperCar ?

Comment: A specific one. (well one will similar arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SuperCar constructor add `: Car(... your arguments ...)` between constructor header and constructor body.

Exemple with code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Car {
    public:
    Car() { }
    // Oh, there is several constructors...
    Car(int weight){
        cout << "Car weight is " << weight << endl;
    }
};

class SuperCar: public Car {
    public:
    // we call the right constructor for Car, detected by call arguments
    // relying on usual function overloading mechanism
    SuperCar(int weight, int height) : Car(weight) {
        cout << "SuperCar height " << height << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    SuperCar(1, 10);
}
```

PS: By the way calling `SuperCar` a subclass of `Car` is confusing, you should probably avoid that.

Answer (score 5):

Sample classes with no member vars.

```
class Car { 
            Car(); /*If you want default objects*/
            Car(/*arg list*/); /* maybe multiple constructors with different, count and 
                                type args */
};

class SuperCar {
           SuperCar(/*args list*/) : Car(/*arg list*/){/*Constructor Body*/}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

example:

```
SuperCar::SuperCar(Parameter p) : Car(p){
   //some voodoo...
}
```

if i remember correctly

edit: damn, kriss was faster :)

Comment: Well, I can't do +1 to my answer but I can to yours, they are the same anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

On your derived class constructor, define an initializer for the base class with the required parameters:

```
SuperCar(/*params*/) : Car(/*differentParams*/)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `SuperCar` constructor will be like,

```
SuperCar(int sayForExample):car(sayForExample),m_SuperCarMember(sayForExample)
{
 // constructor definition
}
```

This will invoke the specific constructor `car(int)` and *initialize* the `SuperCar`'s member `m_SuperCarMember`..

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using initialiser list.

```
SuperCard::SuperCar(args):Car(args){ //Supercar part}
```